# Custom linked Quick Style presets in Powerpoint 2013?

Tags: styles, powerpoint, shapes

I am newbie in Powerpoint and have a very weird problem. Is it possible somehow to add my own shape styles to Quick Styles? If I choose one of presets and then change something (color fill for example) this style is not anymore linked to quick style. And I can't find how to add on my own. And delete all that I don't need.

Any thoughts how to achieve that? I want to create my own shape styles. And link them all over the presentation in order to change quickly color schemes of all elements in presentation. I want to change one linked style to automatic apply to all shapes. Is it possible somehow?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: At least part of this is possible.  For example, assuming you have a style (a collection of formatting attributes) defined and named as a style, your code can apply those attributes to a shape and at the same time apply a TAG to the shape to indicate that the shape's been given a style.  Then when the style attributes change you can iterate through the shapes collections looking for shapes with that style's tag and when found, apply the new formatting.

Answer (score 0):

We are building a [PowerPoint add-in](http://www.veodin.com/slideproof) to do that. You are able to create styles (and select the attributes like color position etc.) then store them to a Library for later use / sharing. Let me know if you are interested to test the current version.